# Draw: vector drawing & technical illustration application

Tags: drawing

I found this very sophisticated Draw application created entirely with the Wolfram Language:

https://github.com/shdlbwr/draw

[image]

The documentation is available here:

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/963158

When I execute `Draw[]` I get the following warning, although I am using Mathematica 11.0.1:

[image]

When I create a drawing, save it as a notebook file and execute this file nothing happens, no drawing is seen.

Do you have experience with this application? How can I save drawings e.g. in png format?

Comment: Like Nasser, I also don't get the message about a newer version of *Mathematica*. However, I've encountered it in the past and if you have *Mathematica* 11 it should be safe to ignore it. The saved notebook file should be opened with the "Open Draw file" button, not by double-clicking it or opening it in *Mathematica* in the normal way; although this would work, it will show you the expression for the graphics rather than the graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just downloaded and tried it. I think this is what one is supposed to do: 1. After you make the drawing first time, like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

then save the notebook. But the notebook is not not meant to be the drawing in graphics format of course. To obtain the actual drawing, use the `copy graphics to clipboard` button

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then paste the image from the clipboard to your any graphics program, say paint.exe  and then save it as png or jpg, etc...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The notebook you save, just contains Mathematica code for the drawing itself. Which you open using the menu:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I open the saved notebook, the drawing is drawn again inside Mathematica Draw app with no problem.

See if this works for you.  Btw, I am using 11.0.1 and I do not get the warning you show.

Comment: Instead of pasting it into Paint I recommend pasting it into a *Mathematica* notebook, then you can save it as whatever format you want. If you paste it into Paint you can only export it in rasterized formats, not SVG or PDF for example. Also you can keep working with the `Graphics` object in the notebook, if desired.

Comment: @Nasser: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @C. E. This is a very good idea ... I did not think about this possibility, thanks.

Comment: Would you @C.E. help answer this question? Thanks.https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198338/draw-application-how-to-edit-text-and-how-to-size-the-figure